# Getting error while fetching data from DB using CodeIgniter and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting the following error while trying to fetch records from database using code-igniter.

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Filename: models/Bookings_model.php

Line Number: 1299

Backtrace:
```

I am providing my query below.

```
$this->db->select('pt_bookings.booking_id,pt_bookings.booking_ref_no,pt_bookings.booking_item,pt_bookings.booking_date,pt_bookings.dep_date,pt_bookings.dep_time,pt_bookings.cutoff_time,pt_bookings.city_id,pt_bookings.src_city,pt_bookings.src_lat,pt_bookings.src_long,pt_bookings.booking_user,pt_bookings.booking_status,pt_bookings.booking_total,pt_bookings.booking_adults,pt_bookings.booking_vehicle,pt_bookings.cron_read,pt_accounts.accounts_id,pt_accounts.ai_first_name,pt_accounts.ai_last_name,pt_accounts.accounts_email,pt_accounts.ai_mobile,pt_tours.tour_id,pt_tours.tour_title,pt_tours.tour_type,pt_tours.tour_location,pt_booking_status.id');
$this->db->join('pt_accounts', 'pt_bookings.booking_user = pt_accounts.accounts_id');
$this->db->join('pt_tours', 'pt_bookings.booking_item = pt_tours.tour_id');
$this->db->where('pt_bookings.booking_status', $sta);
$this->db->where('pt_bookings.cron_read', $cron_read);
$tquery = $this->db->get('pt_bookings')->result();
```

Here using the above query when I am fetching the value but getting the fatal error.

Comment: You are getting this error because the variable `$tquery` is null and thereby not an `object`. You need to check if $tquery is empty first

Comment: try out $this->db->get('pt_bookings')->result_array(); instead of this $this->db->get('pt_bookings')->result();

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the query like this :

```php
    $this->db->select('pt_bookings.booking_id,pt_bookings.booking_ref_no,pt_bookings.booking_item,pt_bookings.booking_date,pt_bookings.dep_date,pt_bookings.dep_time,pt_bookings.cutoff_time,pt_bookings.city_id,pt_bookings.src_city,pt_bookings.src_lat,pt_bookings.src_long,pt_bookings.booking_user,pt_bookings.booking_status,pt_bookings.booking_total,pt_bookings.booking_adults,pt_bookings.booking_vehicle,pt_bookings.cron_read,pt_accounts.accounts_id,pt_accounts.ai_first_name,pt_accounts.ai_last_name,pt_accounts.accounts_email,pt_accounts.ai_mobile,pt_tours.tour_id,pt_tours.tour_title,pt_tours.tour_type,pt_tours.tour_location,pt_booking_status.id');
    $this->db->join('pt_accounts', 'pt_bookings.booking_user = pt_accounts.accounts_id');
    $this->db->join('pt_tours', 'pt_bookings.booking_item = pt_tours.tour_id');
    $this->db->where('pt_bookings.booking_status', $sta);
    $this->db->where('pt_bookings.cron_read', $cron_read);
    $tquery = $this->db->get('pt_bookings');
    if ($tquery->num_rows() > 0) {
        $tquery = $tquery->result();
    } else {
        echo 'no data found.';
    }
```

So when the `$tquery` value is empty it will return the `no data found.` message.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what triggered the error as you're not posting your controller code. However, here's some pointers.

1.- The `$query->result()` method return an **array of objects** so regardless of how many rows are returned, you need to consider the array index or loop through the returned objects.

2.- The `$query->result_array()` method returns an **array of arrays** so the above applies also.

In your controller, you should always check if the returned array does or doesn't contain data. Returning, as per Hasta Dhana's suggestion, a string of text stating "No data found" is not a good idea as it doesn't allow a standard and efficient way to handle this in the controller. My suggestion:

```
$this->db->select('pt_bookings.booking_id,pt_bookings.booking_ref_no,pt_bookings.booking_item,pt_bookings.booking_date,pt_bookings.dep_date,pt_bookings.dep_time,pt_bookings.cutoff_time,pt_bookings.city_id,pt_bookings.src_city,pt_bookings.src_lat,pt_bookings.src_long,pt_bookings.booking_user,pt_bookings.booking_status,pt_bookings.booking_total,pt_bookings.booking_adults,pt_bookings.booking_vehicle,pt_bookings.cron_read,pt_accounts.accounts_id,pt_accounts.ai_first_name,pt_accounts.ai_last_name,pt_accounts.accounts_email,pt_accounts.ai_mobile,pt_tours.tour_id,pt_tours.tour_title,pt_tours.tour_type,pt_tours.tour_location,pt_booking_status.id');
    $this->db->join('pt_accounts', 'pt_bookings.booking_user = pt_accounts.accounts_id');
    $this->db->join('pt_tours', 'pt_bookings.booking_item = pt_tours.tour_id');
    $this->db->where('pt_bookings.booking_status', $sta);
    $this->db->where('pt_bookings.cron_read', $cron_read);
    $tquery = $this->db->get('pt_bookings');

    return ($tquery->num_rows() == 0) ? false : $tquery->result();
```

By returning `false` when no rows were fetched from the database, your controller can determine what to do in a much more standard and future-proofed way. Assuming you called your model from your controller with `$data = $this->your_model->model_method($params);`, you could do something like this right below:

```
if ($data !== false)
{
    // loop through the array or do whatever it is you need to do.
    // since this will happen only when there is actual data being returned, you'll not get the error if no data was fetched
}
```